# Which are the spec bits in this cache?

Tags: computers, computer-architecture, cache

I have a direct mapped cache of size S with the line size L. The cache is physically indexed and tagged. The physical address is 50 bits, numbered from 0 to 49 (with 0 being the least significant bit). The machine has a word size of 4 bits and the memory is byte-addressable. Which bits of the 50 bits are compared with the address tag?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In a direct-mapped cache, each location in memory has exactly one place in which it can be stored in the cache. So, assuming S is given in bytes, this means that the lower log<sub>2</sub>S bits of the address are used to locate the data in the cache. The rest of the address bits become the tag.